Code analysys shows an error, but the code compiles
In the following C code the code analysys (the one from C/C++ vscode extension) highlights an error on DEFINE_INDEXING_FUNCTION macro, but when I compile the code with GCC (gcc -Wall -Wextra filename.c; .\a), it works just fine.
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFINE_INDEXING_FUNCTION(type, array, length)\
    type *_array_indexing_##array = array;\
    type array##_get(long long index) {\
        return __array_indexing_##array[((index) + (length)) % (length)];\
    }

int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

DEFINE_INDEXING_FUNCTION(int, array1, sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int))

#include <stdio.h>

void test() {
    int *array2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

    // expected a ";"
    DEFINE_INDEXING_FUNCTION(int, array2, 10)
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    printf("%d\n", array2_get(-2));
    printf("%d\n", array2_get(2));
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", array1_get(-2));
    printf("%d\n", array1_get(2));
    test();
}

My guess is that it doesn't know nested functions, which are not a part of c standard and are exclusive to gcc.
So, what's the exact reason for that and how to fix the issue?

@KamilCuk Eh. The implied question here is how to fix the intellisense to highlight this correctly. I'd rather edit this (if you don't like this wording) than close the question over semantics.

OP, can you show your c_cpp_properties.json, if any? I believe it has a setting to enable GCC-compatible mode, but I'm not sure if it supports statement expressions. If it doesn't, you can try switching to Clangd instead of the stock C/C++ extension, it surely supports those.

Is type *__array_indexing_##array supposed to match an already-existing, implementation-defined symbol?  If not, symbols that start with two underscores are reserved identifiers: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

@AndrewHenle, no it's not supposed to match anything, I just needed to save a pointer to an array in some variable, that won't show in autocomplete (my main language is python, where double underscore indicates a private attribute) in case it goes out of scope. Although, it's not the point of the question, thank you.

@HolyBlackCat is it supposed to be in project directory or is it in global config? Where do I look for it?

@yurich, Aside (not your current problem), MOD() deserves another ().  #define MOD(a, b) (((a) % (b) + (b)) % (b)).

@chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't notice that the outermost pair was not wrapping the whole expression)

@yurich BTW, are you certain about -1 in length-1?

@yurich "My guess is that it doesn't know nested functions" --> agree. yet I do not use those extensions much. I usually compile with a recent C standard selected.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I just tested it with both length and length-1, somehow both are wrong, I will figure it out

@yurich ,  Instead of int *array2 = malloc(10);, I think you want int *array2 = malloc(sizeof array2[0] * 10);

@chux-ReinstateMonica this code was originally with chars instead of ints, missed this one

@yurich Of course, the data pointed to by array2 need assignments to work with your testing.

yeah, I know, I tested with assignment, int array[] = {1, 2, 3} and 6 testcases. -1,-2,-3,0,1,2 => 1,3,2,1,2,3. I don't think we should discuss this under this question, it's unrelated

I figured it out, the MOD implementation was wrong, I edited it and it now works with just length

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

The 'expected a ";"' suggests it is treating the macro expansion as a function declaration with a missing ;, followed by a compound statement. It is not recognizing it as a function definition.

If compile it with gcc -Wall -Wextra and this shows anything correct with your code, it means GCC compiles your code correctly.

If you are going to write C code then I urge you to learn and use standard C and conventional C idioms.  In particular, C does not have nested functions (though a few compilers provide it as an extension), and it reserves various identifiers whose names begin with underscores or (especially) double underscores.

@JohnBollinger I do, in fact, learn and use the standard C. When I wrote the code I did not have an intention to use non-standard features. I expected the code to fail, as I didn't even know nested functions were a thing, I read about them while troubleshooting. As for the conventional idioms - I will consider learning them. Thank you for your advice!

@SheltonLiu wdym? Maybe "everything" instead of anything? I don't get what you wanted to say

@yurich just help to clarify it’s not gcc compile error… but still need to understand the root cause of error on DEFINE_INDEXING_FUNCTION macro.

@thebusybee It's present in the code, the full text: 'expected a ";"'

"is it supposed to be in project directory or is it in global config? Where do I look for it?" In .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json relative to the project dirrectory.
